# Java - Arduino - Error uploading sketch using IDE (with GUI disabled), but it works from command line

Tags: java, shell, batch-file, command-line, arduino

I'm trying to run this command:

```
"C:\arduino\arduino --upload --board arduino:avr:nano --port COM3 -v ..\config\config.ino"
```

It works from my command line. It takes just a few seconds to run & finish.

The problem comes when I try to execute it from Java with:

```
String cmd = "C:\arduino\arduino --upload --board arduino:avr:nano --port COM3 -v ..\config\config.ino"
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

It takes a minute to execute and ends with:

> Launch 4j: an error occurred while starting the application

I've tried with ProcessBuilder too. I've also tried saving the command to a batch file and then running the batch file from Java...but I just got the same result.

**EDIT:**

If I run the batch file from command line it works too. As I said if I run it from Java, it doesn't.

I've realized that if I run the batch file from another batch file it doesn't work neither.

Maybe there is not a problem at all with Java, but with Arduino IDE.

**EDIT 2:**
Adding "start" parameter before the command and saving it to a batch file seems to work. Then you just run the batch from java.

Something like this:

arduino.bat

```
"start C:\arduino\arduino --upload --board arduino:avr:nano --port COM3 -v ..\config\config.ino"
```

Java code

```
String s = "PATH TO ARDUINO.BAT"
Process p = null;
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(s + "arduino.bat");
pb.directory(new File(s));
p = pb.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is with the relative path at -v argument. Use full path or set
actual working directory with [ProcessBuilder](http://www.java2s.com/Book/Java/0060__Development/Getset_the_working_directory.htm).

Comment: I have checked that and didnt' work. Added more info to the first post.

Comment: Was the two batch files in the same directory?

Comment: Yes they were. I fixed the batch path to point directly to the other batch.

Comment: Try to launch arduino from command line like this: arduino.exe --l4j-debug. It will print more information. I found it on this site: http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=167553.0

Comment: Didn't work because I'm using the non GUI IDE, and it seems that parameter is not accepted. Anyway I think I found a solution. It's not a fancy solution...but works.